# Copy files from mounted volume git pre-commit

Tags: git, bash

Is it possible to use Git pre-commit hooks to copy files from a mounted volume into a repo so that the contents of the volume can be committed with the rest of the repo?

If so, what would the script to do so look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to bring the whole mounted folder into the repo each time:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -r mountdir .; git add mountdir;
```

If you want to copy out the *contents* of the mounted folder into the git repo every time:

```
#!/bin/bash

mntdir="/home/tyssen/mounted"

for f in `ls $mntdir`; do
    cp -r $mntdir/$f .
    git add $f;
done
```

Note the dreaded [parsing of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which someone better than me with globs or `find` can improve upon. Tested and working for me on a local repo.

To copy as in the previous example, but to a path inside the repo (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

mntdir="/home/tyssen/mounted"

for f in `ls $mntdir`; do
    cp -r $mntdir/$f path/in/repo/
    git add path/in/repo/$f;
done
```

Comment: Yep, that's nearly there. Only thing I'd like to do is have the contents copied to a specific folder of the repo. I thought I could add cd /path/to/folder/ to the script, but the contents still get copied into the root of the repo.

Comment: I added an updated example. I tested the `cp` line, but not the git part.

Comment: Thanks, that's 99% perfect. I'm guessing this has to do with the parsing of ls you mentioned earlier, but there's a folder on the mounted drive /_embeds/ - the content of that folder is being copied to the right folder in the repo, but not the folder itself, so I end up with files in the root of the folder I want to copy to when there should just be folders.

Comment: That's odd. I just did this: `mkdir -p foo/_embeds; touch foo/_embeds/bar foo/_embeds/baz; mkdir -p zip/bop; cd zip`, then `basepath='../foo'; cp -r $basepath/$f bop/`, and I ended up with `bar` and `baz` inside `bop/_embeds` (bop being where I was inside of `zip`), so it worked here. You could try to run this script manually from your repo with `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to see if it works on its own (or is that what you're already doing?).

Comment: Yeah, my pre-commit file contains what you had in your second example.